# Is there a way to hide something from "My Tags"?

Tags: support, feature-request, tags

There's some stuff in "My Tags" that I can't answer, and is therefore in the way of stuff I can answer. Is there a way to hide questions that I can't answer?

Comment: For people who are confused about "My Tags": http://askubuntu.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=mytags

Comment: @guntbert: Click on Unanswered > My Tags: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TuKoj.png

Comment: @Aditya, ah I see - I misunderstood your comment completely, it was a general hint about what "my tags" is about :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just add the "tags" that you know you can't answer to the "ignored tags" list.